# Python program to find common authors from the list of citations

Tags: python, nltk, citations

I have a list of citations from different research papers.
For example,

```
['abbasi (2010)',
 'abbasi et al., 2008',
 'abbasi et al., 2011',
 'abbasi, 2010',
 'alani (2011)',
 'atakulreka & sutivong, 2007',
 'baccianella & sebastiani, 2010',
 'bai, 2011',
 'berry & kogan, 2010',
 'bespalov et al. (2011)',
 'bespalov et al., 2011',
 'bishop, 2007',
 'burges (1998)',
 'burges, 1998',
 'burns et al. (2011)']
```

I want to get the list of all authors, but they should not be duplicate.
For example, here, the output I want is

```
['abbasi','alani','atakulreka','sutivong','baccianella','sebastiani',
 'bai','berry','kogan','bespalov','bishop','burges','burns']
```

Anyone please help, as I was not able to figure out how to do it effectively.
One idea I had was to use set intersection, but that did not work.

```
res = set.intersection(*[set(cit.split()) for cit in ALL_CITATIONS])
```

Comment: You can cleaning the items in the list first. Like removing years, symbols and terms like `et al` using regex might help your intersection logic work.

Answer (score 0):

Even something simple like `set([x for x in re.findall('[a-zA-Z]{3,}', ' '.join(data))])` gets you a good list:

```
{'berry', 'bai', 'abbasi', 'atakulreka', 'burns', 'alani', 'baccianella', 'sebastiani', 'sutivong', 'bespalov', 'kogan', 'bishop', 'burges'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like below:

```
res = [[i.split()[0].replace(',','')] if i.split()[1] !='&' else [i.split()[0].replace(',',''),i.split()[2].replace(',','')] for i in l]

res = list(set([val for lst in res for val in lst]))
```

output will be :

```
['burns', 'atakulreka', 'bai', 'bespalov', 'burges', 'sutivong', 'abbasi', 'baccianella', 'kogan', 'alani', 'bishop', 'berry', 'sebastiani']
```